# Cacti is not monitoring the correct host... How do I change SNMP target?

Tags: snmp, cacti

I have been handed a Cacti server that monitors a few hosts.

I noticed that three of the targets were displaying the exact same data - the cacti machine, machine a and machine b.

After doing a bit of digging, I noticed that machine a and machine b had "Local Linux Machine" set under "Host Template".

I have since changed the host template to "Generic SNMP-enabled Host", however, all the graphs still only display data from the local cacti machine (Updates every 5 minutes - I changed this yesterday - 12 hours).

I can't think what else is wrong and was wondering if anyone knows/can recommend anything?

Answer (score 0):

It's the graph template, not the host template.

Changing the Host Template for an existing host doesn't make any changes to existing graphs. It will add extra Data Queries and Graph Templates to the host, only.

The series of templates called things like "Linux - Load Average" work by running a shell script on the Cacti server that (for example) runs 'uptime'. Therefore they will always give you data for the Cacti system itself. You need to switch to using the UCD/Net-SNMP based templates, which will use SNMP to query a remote host.